# Mercurial HG: “hg push” returns abort: HTTP Error 500: No such file or directory

Tags: https, mercurial, repository, hg

I am using mercurial and when I am trying to use hg push, I am getting this error:

```
abort: HTTP Error 500: No such file or directory
```

Server information:

- Nginx with Mercurial
- Debian 7.1

Any idea why? **The pull works fine**.

Comment: Can you please be more specific on "Nginx with Mercurial" topic?

Comment: Sure, On my server, I am using nginx/1.2.1 and Mercurial hg version 2.2.23

Comment: Ok, what backend is used — hgserve or hgweb?

Comment: The hgweb backend is used.

Comment: The configuration files of hgweb, nginx and mercurial, also a `ls -l` to the directory.